# Gibt es ein Adverb für „Wochenende“? (So wie donnerstags für Donnerstag)

Tags: adverb

Gibt es eine adverbiale Form, um „jedes Wochenende“ hier zu ersetzen?

> *An jedem Wochenende* fahre ich ins Saarland.

Ich finde es nicht. Ich habe es mit „wochenendes“ oder „wochenenden“ versucht, aber das richtige Adverb scheint nicht zu existieren.

Comment: ich persönlich halte diese Form für "überflüssig", da der feststehende Term *am Wochenende* leichter zuzuordnen ist als *wochenends*(welches ich an dieser Stelle verwenden würde, wenn es nicht anders ginge), was identisch mit dem Genitiv des Nomens wäre (G-K-Schreibung ausgenommen ;)

Comment: `Donnerstags` heißt mitnichten `an jedem Donnerstag`; es heißt `am Donnerstag`.

Comment: @user unknown: Nicht ganz; es heißt vielleicht nicht "an **jedem** Donnerstag", aber drückt schon eine Gewohnheit/Wiederholung aus. "Am Donnerstag" kann einmalig sein. (Vielleicht ist "an Donnerstagen" synonym?)

Comment: @chirlu: `Kommst Du zum Essen? Donnerstags? Nein, donnerstags geh'n wir ins Kino, mittwochs.` Eine Wiederholung ergibt sich daraus nicht. `Donnerstags gehen wir nie ins Kino - da schaun wir Scobel`. Erst das `nie` verleiht den Charakter der Regelmäßigkeit. `Mittwochs kann ich nicht kommen, da habe ich immer Klavier!` - hier ist es das immer. Ohne ein solches kann es ein regelmäßiger Termin sein, was sich aus dem Kontext erschließen kann; Termine sind ja oft wiederkehrend: `Samstags kann ich nicht zur Herta - ich heirate.` aber nicht immer.

Comment: @user unknown: Vielleicht haben wir da wieder einmal einen regionalen oder sonstigen Unterschied aufgedeckt. Für mich sind dein erstes und letztes Beispiel, also die ohne Wiederholung, falsch.

Comment: Der Duden gibt für [donnerstags](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/donnerstags) als einzige Bedeutung "jeden Donnerstag" an.

Comment: @chirlu: Um gleich ein Beispiel zu bringen, in dem noch ein `immer` davor gesetzt wird. Wozu, wenn es schon `immer` bedeutet?

Comment: Donnerstags ist wie wochentags, nur eben für Donnerstag. Den Satz "Nein, donnerstags geh'n wir ins Kino" halte ich nur dann für richtig, wenn das etwas ist, das jeden Donnerstag stattfindet ("Freitags haben wir bis 12 Uhr Schule.") Ein "immer" braucht es dazu nicht.

Comment: @userunknown: ... und eines ohne *immer*, welches trotzdem "jeden Donnerstag" bedeutet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das Adverb „wochenends“ mag selten benutzt werden, aber es ist leicht belegbar, problemlos verständlich, und ich wüsste nicht, was gegen es sprechen sollte.

[„wochenends“ im Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wochenends)

> Ob man im mittleren Westen Europas einen Professor findet, der wochenends auf die Pürsch geht mit Pfeil und Bogen?

[Peter von Zahn](http://books.google.de/books?id=PxPVAAAAMAAJ&q=%22wochenends%22)
(und nun wende bitte niemand ein, er könne ja auch nicht einmal „Pirsch“ schreiben `;)`)

> Wir überlegen, wie der Alltag eines abends und wochenends schwarzarbeitenden Maurers aussieht: [...]

[Klemens Tilmann](http://books.google.de/books?id=7xAMAQAAMAAJ&q=%22wochenends%22)

> Richard arbeitet ja schon ganz in Meppen und fährt nur wochenends mal nach Hause, so daß Inge mit allem allein zurechtkommen muß, aber sie schafft das glänzend.

[Gerhard Henschel](http://books.google.de/books?id=CgZmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22wochenends%22)

Comment: Soweit ich weiß steht das Wort `wochenends` nicht im Duden.

Comment: @Stan: Mag sein oder auch nicht, aber was würde es bedeuten, wenn es so wäre?

Comment: *Pürsch*? Ich dachte, es heißt *Pirsch*? Von *anpirschen*?

Comment: @chirlu: nichts, als eine Anmerkung! Ich bin *für* sinnvolle neue Wörter :)

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: Zu Hülf’, die Herren Grimm s.v. [pirsch](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=pirsch)!

Answer (score 3):

### an Wochenenden

Die korrekte Form des Satzes wäre

> An Wochenenden fahre ich ins Saarland.

Es gibt zwar `wochentags` aber (leider) **nicht** `wochenends`. Ich habe schon Leute getroffen, die `wochenends` (unkorrekterweise) verwenden, aber der richtige Ausdruck ist, wie oben gesagt, `an Wochenenden`.
Ich denke, dass es nicht so schlimm wäre `wochenends` in der Umgangssprache zu verwenden, aber bei geschriebenen Texten sollte man die korrekte Form, `an Wochenenden`, verwenden.

Answer (score 1):

Es existiert kein Adverb für das Substantiv Wochenende. Jedenfalls kein geläufiges, welches auch wirklich in der deutschen Sprache benutzt wird.

Der Satz

```
Am jeden Wochenende fahre ich nach dem Saarland.
```

ist jedoch falsch.

Richtig lautet es:

```
An jedem Wochenende fahre ich in das Saarland.
```

Auch wenn das Wochenende ein Neutrum ist, wird es in diesem Fall als Genus behandelt.

Comment: also one can very well say *nach dem Saarland*, grammatically fine, just very damn old...

Comment: Or used in the *Paderborn* area: *Komm ma nachm Bahnhof unn hol mich!*

Answer (score 1):

As far as a true adverb is concerned... there is none. In theory, you could also use this phrasing

> Des/Jeden Wochenendes fahre ich ins Saarland.

But this is "HIGHLIESTLY" unidiomatic. It's an epic phrasing for a mundane fact so you could use it as a joke maybe.
The most common phrasing would be this:

> Jedes Wochenende fahre ich ins Saarland.

There is a word *wochenendlich* but people use it more as a joke ... that is, they are aware that it is not a real word and they assume that the listener is aware of that too. 
([here](http://forum.wetteronline.de/showthread.php?t=94194), it plays with the title of a movie)

Comment: Downvote speak up!